# How can I get only last run of each SSIS job using T-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image: Table screenshot]

How can I get only the last run of each SSIS job using a T-SQL query?

Please check the image. These details are stored in a single Table XYZ. Can anyone help me by providing a T-SQL query?

I am using this query:

```
select Job_Name, Start_Date, Finish_Time, Remarks 
from #XYZ 
order by Job_Name
```

Comment: Edit the question add sample output too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select x.*
from (select x.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by job_name order by try_convert(datetime, Finish_Time) desc) as seq
      from #XYZ x
     ) x
where x.seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a `row_number` to sort the data and then filtering to where a `1` is returned:

```
select cols
from(select cols
           ,row_number() over (partition by Job_Name order by Start_Date desc) as rn
     from table
    ) as t
where rn = 1
```